# Writing character device driver, ioctl() vs normal read/write?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, driver

I've been toying with writing a character device module for the linux kernel and I came to a bit of a confusing stop.

I see online there is talk of using `ioctl()` to transfer commands/data from user programs to kernel space and vice-versa. But a lot of it seems like overkill to do what is already possible with the `file_operations struct`

```
// structure containing callbacks
static struct file_operations fops = 
{
    .read = dev_read, // address of dev_read
    .open = dev_open,  // address of dev_open
    .write = dev_write, // address of dev_write 
    .release = dev_rls, // address of dev_rls
};
```

What benefit is there to using `ioctl()` instead of using function defined at `dev_read()` and `dev_write()` that simply copy chunks of data to/from user land with `copy_to_user()` and `copy_from_user()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ioctl` should only be used for those operations that aren't provided by default in the kernel.

Having to call `ioctl` to read or write data to your device takes away a lot of the ease of use you have when using the simple `read` or `write` calls.

By non-standard operations I mean things like setting up automatic ASCII/EBCDIC translation in a terminal device driver, or ejecting a disk from your DVD block device, or modifying serial communications parameters (baud rate, stop bits, etc) for serial communications devices.

By all means use `ioctl` to transfer commands to (or get non-data-information like current parameters or statistics from) your device driver (the alternative is to use some complicated escaping scheme in the data like the `AT` command set for modems or (and this is showing my age) the <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> for the Apple ][ disk subsystem, and that's rarely pretty.

Leave the data transfer to the standard calls.

Comment: Why couldn't you use read/write to do non-standard operations? You could easily transfer a command/argument via read/write. I'm failing to see the reason ioctl exists at all?

Comment: @John, separation of duties basically. If you intermix data and control on a single channel, it's a chore to keep them separate, especially for async operations.It's no different to the two FTP TCP sessions that are used to control transfers. The data travels exclusively on one sesion, control on the other, allowing easy separation of out-of-band information. Think of what happens if your commands all start with `xyzzy` and the device driver intercepts those on the `write` call. Now what happens when you want to send the string `xyzzy` to the actual _device_ (eg. terminal) itself?

Comment: Ah I guess that makes more sense, for my use I can combine data/control because I have a very small control set and data that has a limited(non-negative) set of values, but if my values used the full range that wouldn't work.